# Extjs Tooltips, IFrames and IE => Problems

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, extjs, openlayers

I have an application using `OpenLayers`, `Extjs` and `GeoExt`. My application runs fine, but I need it to be placed inside an `IFrame` in another page. When doing this, my toolbar becomes responseless in *Internet Explorer*.

The cause is **Ext.QuickTips.init();**. Comment out this line and everything works fine - except the quick tips ofcourse =)

But why is it causing problems? Is it because I'm using it wrong, placing it wrong or just because it doesn't like *Internet Explorer* and `IFrames`?

---

**Link**:

[Link to the IFrame page](http://www.gis34.dk/iframetest.html)

**IFrame** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe height="660" src="http://www.gis34.dk/doctype.html" width="660">
          <p>This browser does not support <i>frames</i>.</p>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Application** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var map;
        var mapPanel;
        var mainViewport;
        var toolbarItems = [];
    </script>
    <link href="/Libraries/Ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Libraries/GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/CSS/Extjs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/CSS/OpenLayers.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/CSS/Poseidon.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/Libraries/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Libraries/Ext/adapter/ext/ext-base-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Libraries/Ext/ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Libraries/GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.QuickTips.init(); // Uncomment this line!

            Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/Libraries/Ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';

            var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik('OpenStreetMap Mapnik', {
                sphericalMercator: true
            }, {
                isBaseLayer: true
            });

            var mapOptions = {
                projection: 'EPSG:900913',
                units: 'm',
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(1390414.0280576, 7490505.7050394, 1406198.2743956, 7501990.3685372),
                minResolution: '0.125',
                maxResolution: '1000',
                restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(1390414.0280576, 7490505.7050394, 1406198.2743956, 7501990.3685372),
                controls: [
                    ]
            };
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('', mapOptions);

            var Navigation = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation();
            action = new GeoExt.Action({
                control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
                    out: false
                }),
                map: map,
                tooltip: "Zoom in",
                iconCls: 'icon-zoom-in',
                toggleGroup: 'mapTools',
                group: 'mapTools'
            });
            toolbarItems.push(action);
            action = new GeoExt.Action({
                control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
                    out: true
                }),
                map: map,
                tooltip: "Zoom out",
                iconCls: 'icon-zoom-out',
                toggleGroup: 'mapTools',
                group: 'mapTools'
            });
            toolbarItems.push(action);

            action = new GeoExt.Action({
                control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent(),
                map: map,
                iconCls: 'icon-zoom-max-extent',
                tooltip: 'Zoom helt ud'
            });
            toolbarItems.push(action);
            map.addControl(Navigation);
            map.addLayer(layer);

            mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
                border: true,
                id: 'mapPanel',
                region: "center",
                map: map,
                tbar: toolbarItems
            });
            mainViewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout: "fit",
                hideBorders: true,
                items: {
                    layout: "border",
                    deferredRender: false,
                    items: [
                        mapPanel
                        ]
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across a similar issue, IE behaves whacky in an iframe.

It seems the issue is related to unmasking of elements.

Quicktips gets disabled on mousedown of the document by the drag drop manager, then enabled on mouseup. On enable, it unmasks the element and attempts to remove a class, which seems to cause it. I honestly don't know why.

Anyway, in the unmask() method, try modifying the code so it only calls removeClass if an existing mask was already there.

`unmask : function(){
    var me = this,
        dom = me.dom,
    mask = data(dom, 'mask'),
    maskMsg = data(dom, 'maskMsg'),
        hasMask;`

```
if(mask){
    if(maskMsg){
        maskMsg.remove();
            data(dom, 'maskMsg', undefined);
    }
    mask.remove();
        data(dom, 'mask', undefined);
        hasMask = true;
}
if(hasMask){
        me.removeClass([XMASKED, XMASKEDRELATIVE]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I really don't know what to look for. No errors occur and I'm not that experienced with ExtJS to know how it should behave at this level. Can you give me a hint where to look?

Is this a problem in IE or is it ExtJS which is not flexible enough to support IE AND IFrames? I other words, is this something I have to find a workaround for and maintain in future ExtJS Versions or is it something that ought to be implemented generally from ExtJS?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in SVN. It has nothing to do with ExtJS, it's some whacky bug in IE. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have inserted your suggested code in the *ext-all-debug.js* replacing the old code. The link now point to my modified *ext-all-debug.js* file, but it still doesn't work. Are the more to it than just the code you kindly have posted? The issue are both in IE7 and IE8.

I don't have access to the SVN yet, but that should change as soon as my boss says go to buy the license :)